# Consume OAuth based SOAP web service in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, soap

I want invoke soap web service which is protected with OAuth from my spring boot application, i did not get how to use webclient with WebServiceTemplate or way to do the automatic way of getting the token and setting it to request header , like web client.

wanted to know if there anyway springboot handle this scenario out of the box?